# Laravel Php 8.1 how to convert enum cases to array for select input

Tags: php, laravel, enums, laravel-filament

I got this enum class of periods or terms:

*Term.php*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

enum Term : string
{
    case ONE_MONTH = '1 month';
    case THREE_MONTHS = '3 months';
    case SIX_MONTHS = '6 months';
    case TWELVE_MONTHS = '12 months';
}
```

So I have tested the following with dump

```php
dd(array_map(
   fn (Term $term) => $term->value,
   Term::cases()
));
```

it outputs:

```php
^ array:4 [▼
  0 => "1 month"
  1 => "3 months"
  2 => "6 months"
  3 => "12 months"
]
```

Now I want to pass each value into a Select input (of [filamentphp.com](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#select) ) like so:

```php
Forms\Components\Select::make('term')->options([
       array_map(
          fn (Term $term) => $term->value,
          Term::cases()
       )
   //Term::ONE_MONTH->value=>TERM::ONE_MONTH->name
]),
```

But I get the following error:

> Filament\Forms\Components\Select::isOptionDisabled(): Argument #2 ($label) must be of type string, array given,

Well, it looks like I need to get the following syntax (as shown in the [documentation](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/fields#select)):

```php
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
 
Select::make('status')
    ->options([
        'draft' => 'Draft',
        'review' => 'In review',
        'published' => 'Published',
    ])
```

So what am I missing to get the enum class values displayed in an input form?

Answer (score 3):

Just tried your code locally and based on your code I see that you are passing an array to filament select option. As the error says you **should pass a string into label**. But you are passing an array to it. Check below dump it will pass 0 as the value and array ( `"ONE_MONTH" => "1 month"`) as the label.

```
^ array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "ONE_MONTH" => "1 month"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "THREE_MONTHS" => "3 months"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "SIX_MONTHS" => "6 months"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "TWELVE_MONTHS" => "12 months"
  ]
]
```

Just mapping enums as key-value paire will fix the issue

```
 $terms = [];

 foreach (Term::cases() as $value) {
   $terms[$value->name] = $value->value;
 }
```

Above code will return an array like below

```
^ array:4 [▼
  "ONE_MONTH" => "1 month"
  "THREE_MONTHS" => "3 months"
  "SIX_MONTHS" => "6 months"
  "TWELVE_MONTHS" => "12 months"
]
```

I have tested with one of my local project and see below working screenshots
and code

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {

        $values = [];

        foreach (Term::cases() as $value) {
            $values[$value->name] = $value->value;
        }
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Select::make('terms')
                    ->options($values),
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your enum class add this function

```
public static function toArray(): array
{
    $array = [];
    foreach (self::cases() as $case) {
        $array[$case->value] = $case->name;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
Term::toArray();
```

Comment: I think it should be `$array[$case->name] = $case->value;` Since value can have white space

Answer (score 1):

```
\Illuminate\Support\Arr::map(Term::cases(), fn($enum) => $enum->value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array_column(ProductStatusEnum::cases(), 'value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works

importe

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Enum;
```

....

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('term')
     ->options(Term::class)
     ->default(Term::ONE_MONTH)
     ->rules([new Enum(Term::class)])
     ->disablePlaceholderSelection()
     ->required()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using filament version 3.x, it is as simple as the following

```php
Forms\Components\Select::make('term')
    ->options(App\Enums\Term::class)
```

Reference: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/support/enums#enum-labels